# d3 collapse tree - semantic zoom and pan example - problems

Tags: d3.js, tree, zooming, panning

i found this [working exmaple](http://jsfiddle.net/6kEpp/2/) in this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14666543/d3-js-semantic-zoom-and-pan-example-not-working). I used this example to make my own tree able to zoom and pan but there are a few bugs. So here are my questions.

1. What can i do to not transform the lines if i click in the background?
2. What can i do to not show the tree in standard zoom and pan position after clicking a 
   node. Its because my click event triggers update but i dont find a solution.
   Here is the update function form the working example:

update(root);

```
function update(source) {
  var duration = d3.event && d3.event.altKey ? 5000: 500;

  // Compute the new tree layout.
  var nodes = tree.nodes(root).reverse();

  // Normalize for fixed-depth.
  nodes.forEach(function (d) { d.y = d.depth * 180; });

  // Update the nodes...
  var node = vis.selectAll("g.node")
      .data(nodes, function(d) { return d.id || (d.id = ++i); });

  // Enter any new nodes at the parent's previous position.
  var nodeEnter = node.enter().append("svg:g")
      .attr("class", "node")
      .attr("transform", function(d) {return "translate(" + source.y0 + "," + source.x0 + ")"; })
      .on("click", function(d) {
          toggle(d);
          update(d);
          if (d['info']) {
              playvid(d['info']);
          }
      });

  nodeEnter.append("svg:circle")
      .attr("r", 1e-6)
      .style("fill", function(d) { return d._children ? "lightsteelblue" : "#fff"; });

  nodeEnter.append("svg:text")
      //.attr("y", function(d) { return d.children || d._children ? -10 : 10; })
      //.attr("dx", ".35em")
      .attr("x", function(d) { return d.children || d._children ? -10 : 10; })
      .attr("dy", ".35em")
      .attr("text-anchor", function(d) { return d.children || d._children ? "end" : "start"; })
      .text(function(d) { return d.name; })
      .style("fill-opacity", 1e-6);

  // Transition nodes to their new position.
  var nodeUpdate = node.transition()
      .duration(duration)
      .attr("transform", function(d) { return "translate(" + d.y + "," + d.x + ")"; });

  nodeUpdate.select("circle")
      .attr("r", 4.5)
      .style("fill", function(d) { return d._children ? "lightsteelblue" : "#fff"; });

  nodeUpdate.select("text")
      .style("fill-opacity", 1);

  // Transition exiting ndoes to the parent's new position.
  var nodeExit = node.exit().transition()
      .duration(duration)
      .attr("transform", function(d) { return "translate(" + source.y + "," + source.x + ")"; })
      .remove();

  nodeExit.select("circle")
      .attr("r", 1e-6);
  nodeExit.select("text")
      .style("fill-opacity", 1e-6);

  // Update the links...
  var link = vis.selectAll("path.link")
      .data(tree.links(nodes), function(d) { return d.target.id; });

  // Enter any new links at hte parent's previous position
  link.enter().insert("svg:path", "g")
      .attr("class", "link")
      .attr("d", function(d) {
        var o = {x: source.x0, y: source.y0};
        return diagonal({source: o, target: o});
      })
      .transition()
        .duration(duration)
        .attr("d", diagonal);

  // Transition links to their new position.
  link.transition()
      .duration(duration)
      .attr("d", diagonal);

  // Transition exiting nodes to the parent's new position.
  link.exit().transition()
      .duration(duration)
      .attr("d", function(d) {
        var o = {x: source.x, y: source.y};
        return diagonal({source: o, target: o});
      })
      .remove();

  // Stash the old positions for transition.
  nodes.forEach(function(d) {
    d.x0 = d.x;
    d.y0 = d.y;
  });
}
```

Thanks for the time.

Comment: For the first question, you would need to attach the zoom behaviour only to the nodes and lines. For the second question it sounds as if you would want the normal (i.e. non-semantic) zoom.

Comment: Great, I'll post this as an answer for reference then.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For the first question, you would need to attach the zoom behaviour only to the nodes and lines. For the second question it sounds as if you would want the normal (i.e. non-semantic) zoom.